# Accessing values through bracket notation with a variable in bracket after looping through struct for field names

Tags: go

I have 2 JSON files one containing users, and another containing email templates

I'm looping through the code in the email templates, and when there is a key as a value, like this:

```
"keyToFind": "Username"
```

Then I want to get the value for Username in the other JSON file:

```
"Username": "ssmith"
```

KeyToFind can be a few different things, like Password or Group and I want to avoid writing a specific if statement

I'm trying to do this in my loop but it appears that I can't use a variable in bracket notation

```
for _, emailElements := range emailTemplates.EmailSpecification {
                for _, fieldName := range structs.Names(&User{}) {
                    if emailElements.KeyToFind == fieldName {
                        EmailBody.WriteString(user[fieldName])
                    }
                }
```

What the above is trying to do is loop through the elements in the email template, and then the fields in the Users struct; where an emailElement in the template JSON file of type KeyToFind is gotten, and this is the same as a field name in the struct; look up the user **value** for the KeyToFind

I could do this in Python without a problem

**How can I rewrite line 4 to work in Go? --> user[FieldName]**

The error I get is:

```
user[fieldName] (type User does not support indexing)
```

But if I write line 4 again to this:

```
user.Username
```

It will work fine, but that's obviously only for usernames, they could be Password or Group for the value in KeyToFind

**Here are the JSON files:**

Email template:

```
    "emailName": "customer",
    "emailSpecification": [
        {
            "emailSubject": "Hi"
        },
        {
            "text": "Username: "
        },
        {
            "keyToFind": "Username"
        }
]
```

**I want to get the value of KeyToFind and search the properties in the User file and return the value from that property**

User file:

```
[
{
    "UserType": "customer",
    "Username": "ssmith",
    "Password": "sophie"
}
]
```

Comment: yes, you use the selector (the `.`) to access struct fields, which you've shown. You know the fields of the structs you want, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You can not change the behavior of square notation in Go. What you can do is use a library like [jsonparser](https://github.com/buger/jsonparser) or some other good, performant json library instead of encoding/json and use that instead of reflection.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically select the following field after the dot, so it's from a variable and not hardcoded. This would mean that I can look up values from one JSON file, based on a configuration that I write in another.

Comment: You can't dynamically change the code in a statically typed/compiled language. You can easily do this with reflection, but that's rarely what you should be doing. Can you better explain _why_ you think you need to " dynamically select the following field after the dot"?

Comment: @IshanJain Thanks, i'll take a look

Comment: @JimB - i'm creating a series of email templates, where the config of the templates is done in a JSON file. The data to be used for some of the values is in another file. I need to be able to have it dynamic because the templates are scanned through and where there is an element called keyToFind in the email template, wwe take the value, and then look up the value in the data file for that value from the KeyToFind

Comment: If you are doing this to increase speed of your program, I'll strongly recommend that you write benchmarks comparing your current version of code and another version using `jsonparser`.

Comment: Meaning that KeyToFind: Username, will do this --> "look in Users JSON file, find the value for the Username"

Comment: Also, You should save the result of `structs.Names(&User{})` once in a variable before iterating over templates instead of calling that function for every template.

Comment: I guess over speed it's more flexibility. I'm not even sure if this is possible in Go

Comment: @MassiveOwl With encoding/json? It's not.

Comment: if this is for templating, aren't these all strings? Wouldn't a simple map make more sense?

Comment: @MassiveOwl Why you are not giving a more detail of your code?

Comment: I will edit the question...

Comment: I think this should make more sense now, so in the JSON emailtemplate, KeyToFind is Username, I want to scan the Users data file, search for the property that's the value of KeyToFind, then gets the user's value

Comment: @MassiveOwl: you user file is a list of maps, just use maps and you don't have to worry about reflection (either directly or through some helper package) at all.

Comment: @JimB I got it using a map conversion! Thanks a lot - i'll add an answer now

Comment: There's 3 main ways to do this, listed in no particular order: 1) Reflection 2) Not using the `User` type, but using `map[string]interface{}`, 3) Using a `siwtch` 4) Mapping the `User` type onto a map where each key holds a pointer to the corresponding field. All in all, though, I'd avoid using reflection, or the mapping malarkey, and a switch is such a clunky thing to use most of the time. I'd use a map

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanksfor the succinct explanation. I used a map for your reasons

Answer (score 0):

I got it by converting the User struct to a map, once it's a map you can use the bracket notation *with dot notation inside*

In my context, I then had to convert to a string to pass into WriteString function that buffer needs

Here is the final version:

```
for _, emailElements := range emailTemplates.EmailSpecification {
                for _, fieldName := range structs.Names(&User{}) {
                    if emailElements.KeyToFind == fieldName {
                        EmailBody.WriteString(structs.Map(user)[emailElements.KeyToFind].(string))
                    }
                }
}
```

It's using the package:

```
"github.com/fatih/structs"
```

Comment: Just a side-note: the package you use is relying on reflection underneath. I'd recommend you not use the `User` type to begin with, and just work with a raw map. It'll  perform far, far better

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do